# How to populate DataTable using Stored Procedure on Entity Framework DF

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a stored procedure `GetAllUsers` which returns all the columns from a the table `Users`.

Here is a sample of a the DataTable I want to achieve.

[image]

I'm using Entity Framework (Database First).

**Stored Procedure**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetAllUsers]
AS
BEGIN

      SELECT * FROM Users
END
```

**Controller**

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // Create ViewModel/ResourcViewModel instance
        var vm = new ResourceViewModel();

       // Code to fetch data from Stored Procedure and display to DataTable
    }
```

**View Model**

```
public class ResourceViewModel
{
    // Dropdown Properties
    public int UserID { set; get; }
    public string FirstName { set; get; }
    public string LastName { set; get; }
}
```

**View**

```
<table class="table" id="dataTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
           <th class="text-center">First Name</th>
           <th class="text-center">Last Name</th>
           <th class="text-center">Actions</th>

       </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Wick</td>
        <td><button class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">iew Details</button>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Black</td>
        <td>Panther</td>
        <td><button class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">View Details</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Once I have displayed the list of users into the DataTable. I want to bind the `UserID` to my `View Details` button.

Comment: So, where do you need help? on calling the stored procedure from EF or binding the UserID into the table's button?

Comment: Both. But I think I can get it once I display the results from the DataTable.

Answer (score 0):

1.Calling the stored procedure from EF

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    using (DBContext dbContext = new DBContext())
    {
         // Code to fetch data from Stored Procedure
         var vm = dbContext.[YourStoredProcedureName].Select(new ResourceViewModel(){... set values here}).ToList();
         return view(vm);
    }        
}
```

2. Binding the UserID

   ```
   @model IEnumerable<ResourceViewModel>
     <table>
       <tr>           
           //set th
       </tr>    
       @foreach (var item in Model)
       {
           <tr>
               //set td
               <td>
                   @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id })//here you can change it to ViewDetails action link
               </td>
           </tr>
       }
   </table>
   ```